# Record order value by day of the week

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the record order value by day of the week, based a table with these columns:

```
id
amount
date
```

I was wondering if there's an easy way of doing this in MySQL?

I was thinking of grouping the amount by the day, and grouping the days by day of the week and then retrieving only the highest value. I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want; it finds the maximum total for each day of the week and then `JOIN`s that to the totals for each day to find the day on which each weekday's maximum occurred:

```
SELECT t.weekday, t.date, t.total
FROM (SELECT date, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%W') AS weekday, SUM(amount) AS total
      FROM yourtable
      GROUP BY date) t
JOIN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%W') AS weekday, MAX(total) AS max_total
      FROM (SELECT date, SUM(amount) AS total
            FROM yourtable
            GROUP BY date) t
      GROUP BY weekday) w ON w.weekday = t.weekday AND w.max_total = t.total
```

Output (for my demo)

```
weekday     date        total
Thursday    2019-04-11  110.00
Friday      2019-04-12  100.00
Saturday    2019-04-20  180.00
Sunday      2019-04-21  50.00
Monday      2019-04-22  160.00
Tuesday     2019-04-23  50.00
Wednesday   2019-04-24  230.00
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=22ec92c45cdc65c127c284f3dd204c3d)

Comment: Thanks Nick. I don’t think this would find the record value for that day of the week, but I think my question isn’t clear. I’m looking to find the best date for sales, so for example say this Friday was the best Friday we ever had, it would return Friday, 19-05-03, £X. It would return all of the other days of the week with the record date too.

Comment: It’s close, I’m just editing on dbfiddle. It seems only return Monday on dbfiddle, not the highest for each day of the week

Comment: @jdawg it seems to work ok for me with different results: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=af309fe498ec64e7fcfb53aee7f91ee3

Comment: It’s only returning a single day, not the highest for each day of the week. I think it needs another group, I’m just fiddling about with it now

Comment: @jdawg I think I have what you want now...